# Dot plot with many levels of information

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
            avg.exp     pct.exp       features  cl 
         3.035491e-02  1.5552100          ACPP  2 
         6.146265e-03  0.3576983          AZU1  1 
         9.433765e+00 48.8491446          CD63  1 
         5.344578e-04  0.0311042          CTSG  2
         4.180587e+39  9.4401244         DEFA3  3 
         3.413496e-02  1.2752722         DEFA4  3
```

Is there a way to generate a dot plot where on the x axis are reported the features, on the y-axis the cl, the color of the dots is continuous (avg.exp) and the size of the dots is pct.exp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(df,aes(y=cl,x=features,color=avg.exp)) + geom_point(aes(size=pct.exp))
```